# Rewrite URL with .htaccess for 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I convert URL from:
*http://example.com/site/delete-page.php?site=first&page=second*

To:
*http://example.com/site/first/delete-page/second*

Thank You!

Comment: A general hint: such questions often receive bad feedback. The guidelines how to ask questions here clearly state two things: 1. you are expected to have a minimum understanding of the topic your question deals with and 2. you are expected to show own effort to have solved the issue _before_ asking here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal rule for that specific task:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/([^/]+)/delete-page/(.+)$ /site/delete-page.php?site=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

To use the same rule inside a `.htaccess` style file you have to modify it slightly: remove the leading slash (`/`) from pattern and target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]+)/delete-page/(.+)$ site/delete-page.php?site=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This assumes that the `.htaccess` style file is located inside the folder holding the `site` folder. You can also place the file inside that `site` folder, then obviously you have to remove the `site/` part from the rules pattern and target. Also you have to take care that the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is enabled at all for that host and location.

---

In general you should always prefer the first version and place such rules inside your http servers host configuration. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow the server down. They are only offered as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the server configuration. For example when using a really cheap shared web hoster service...